# Bash Sorting Redirection

Tags: linux, bash

What are the differences between `sort file1 -o file2` and `sort file1 > file2` ? So far from what I have done they do the same thing but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: There is no difference, AFAIK.

Comment: In the latter case the shell is handling the redirection from stdout to file2.  In the former case, sort opens its own fd for file2 to write

Comment: @l19 That's not true. Get surprised while specifying same input and output file.

Comment: @jkshah That's correct. The difference becomes obvious when redirecting to the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is the same but in the case of `-o file2` the resulting file is created by `sort` directly while in the other case, it is created by `bash` and filled with the standard output of `sort`. The `xfopen` defined in line 450 of `sort.c` in coreutils treats both cases (`stdout` and `-o filename`) equally.

Redirecting the standard output of `sort` is more generic as it could be redirected to another program with a `|` in place of a `>`, which the `-o` option makes more difficult to do (but not impossible)

The `-o` option is handy for in place sorting as the redirection to the same file will lead to a truncated file because it is created (and truncated) by the shell prior to the invocation of `sort`.

Answer (score 5):

Following two commands are similar as long as `file1` and `file2` are different.

```
sort file1 -o file2    # Output redirection within sort command
sort file1 > file2     # Output redirection via shell
```

Let's see what happens when input and output files are same `file` i.e. you try to sort in-place

```
sort file -o file      # Works perfectly fine and does in-place sorting
sort file > file       # Surprise! Generates empty file. Data is lost :(
```

In summary, **above two redirection methods are similar but not the same**

Test

```
$ cat file
2
5
1
4
3
$ sort file -o file
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
$ sort file > file
$ cat file
$ ls -s file
0 file
```

Comment: Obvious: With `sort file > file`, bash will _first_ open `file` for writing, erasing its content (unless `noclobber` is set), and _then_ launch `sort file`... that will be launched with an empty file.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much difference `>` is a standard unix output redirection function. That is to say 'write your output that you would otherwise display on the terminal to the given file' The -o option is more specific to the sort function. It is a way to again say 'write the output to this given file'

The `>` can be used where a tool does not specifically have a write to file argument or option.