# Why does in-place sort of same file fail?

Tags: bash, sorting

The sort command doesn't behave as expected when redirecting with stdout as stated here: [sort command question] ([Bash Sorting Redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894116/bash-sorting-redirection/))!

My question is, why does the following fail?

```
sort file > file       # Surprise! Generates empty file. Data is lost :(
```

Does it have to do with write permissions with the shell in specific distros or is it something else?  If it is only a write permission problem, how can it be made to work (not that it should be made to work)?  Shouldn't file just be overwritten first?

Comment: It's got to do with reading from the file and writing to it at the same time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can ls see the future when using bash redirection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026881/how-can-ls-see-the-future-when-using-bash-redirection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell sets up the redirection before the command runs and when the shell opens the file for writing it immediately truncates the contents of the file. `sort` never has a chance to see them.

From the bash [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Redirection
>
> Before a command is executed, its input and output may be redirected
>   using a special notation interpreted by the shell. Redirection may
>   also be used to open and close files for the current shell execution
>   environment. The following redirection operators may precede or appear
>   anywhere within a simple command or may follow a command. Redirections
>   are processed in the order they appear, from left to right.

Comment: With "sort file < file", shouldn't it not save the completed operation?  Also for stdout (>), is your answer the general case for all redirect operations given to a command for the same file?  I would've thought the contents would've just been overwritten from the cursory description the book I have gives me.  With multiple stdout or stdin operations, like "sort file > file > sort file", what would be the order that the shell takes before running the command?  Is it left to right or vice versa?  Thanks.

Comment: `sort > file > sort file` is going to create (and clobber) the file `file` and then create (and clobber) the file `sort` then try to sort `file` and write output to `sort`.

Comment: You can easily test that with `echo > file1 > file2 'some message'` and then seeing which files exist and which has content.

Comment: True enough.  But I was looking for clear language and terminology compared to the responses that have been given.

Comment: `sort file < file` is going to ignore `stdin` and sort `file` from the argument.

Comment: The contents of the output file *are* overwritten, immediately. Because the file itself is truncated. Otherwise you would get partial old results if you wrote less data or end up needing to truncate at the end (which would mean incorrect results if you terminated early).

Comment: Meant to say "should it not save the completed operation in the first comment".  With "sort -r file < file < sort file" - I get: "bash: sort: No such file or directory".  I guess using the command's option(s) and piping is better for any operations that require multiple operations of data.

Comment: Ok, I'll learn about the term clobber and read the bash reference manual talked about in the referenced post's comments.

Comment: clobber isn't a bash specific term it just means hit/destroy/etc. in this case it means "erase all data in". (The bash man page does use the term in a technical sense though.) `sort -r file < file < sort file` is trying to redirect from `file` then from `sort` then passing `-r file` to the sort command. Each `< name` is a redirection and is removed from processing for the final command to run. And note that you will *not* get contents from both files in a construction like that.